# Different development environments with docker

Tags: docker

What is the best way to separate different projects development environments with docker ?

Talking about Mac, when it was not native supported, I used to have two docker-machine, lets say projectA and projectB, so I just `eval $(docker-machine env projectA)` in order to access all the containers for this project.

In terms of containers I had:

ProjectA:

- MySQL
- MongoDB
- ActiveMQ
- Cassandra

ProjectB:

- MySQL
- MongoDB

Is it possible to have such separation so anyone that does `docker ps -a` will only see the containers related to the currently selected machine?

I can keep doing this with docker-machine but then it will not use native-enabled features and perform slower.

Thanks!

Comment: if you use `docker-compose` you can do `docker-compose ps` and it should show only containers related to the local compose file

Answer (score 1):

Docker isn't natively supported on the Mac - Docker for Mac uses [native *virtualization*](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/#/what-to-know-before-you-install), but there's still a Linux VM running which the Docker client connects to.

You're right that the performance and integration is better with Docker for Mac but the trade-off is that you only get one VM, you can't create a second VM and have two Docker engines running, which is the only way to physically segregate containers.

Docker for Mac and Docker Toolbox [can coexist](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/docker-toolbox/#/docker-toolbox-and-docker-for-mac-coexistence), so that's one option. The other option is to segregate them logically - by running related containers in the same Docker network - but they'd still all show in `docker ps`.